# weak convergence : probability measures, is limit finite?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Assume that there is a sequence of measures $\mu^{n}$ all defined on $\mathbb{R}^{N}$, where the sigma algebra is Borel. Furthermore $\mu^{n}$ is assumed to be tight. I know that Prohorov's theorem implies that for every subsequence $n_{k}$ it is true that $\mu^{n_{k}}$ has a limit. Say that for one such subsequence we have $\mu^{n_{k}}\to \mu$. Is it true that $\mu$ is finite and non-zero? Assume that $\mu^{n}$ is probability measure for all $n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathbb R^N$ is both open and closed, we have $1=\lim_{k\to \infty}\mu_{n_k}(\mathbb R^N)=\mu(\mathbb R^N)$, so $\mu$ is a probability measure.